# Counting function and its Artin L-function

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, l-functions, euler-product

I am working with the following function: given a polynomial, $P(x)$, with non-negative integer coefficients and passing through origin, we can define
$$f(d)=\{1\leq a\leq d \ | \ P(a)\equiv 0 \mod(d)\}$$
It is easy to see that $f$ is a multiplicative function. I am interested in the L-function associated with $f$, that is,
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{f(n)}{n^s}=\prod_{p \ \text{prime}}\left(1+\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{f(p^k)}{p^{sk}}\right)^{-1}$$
I need to show the following that the above L-function is analytic in $\Re(s)>1$ and it has a pole of order $n$ at $s=1$ where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial $P(x)$. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have a lot of conflicting notation in your question. On one hand $p$ denotes a polynomial, but then it denotes a prime. You also define $f_p$, but then use $f$ (I'm assuming this is just $f_p$?). Additionally, the last displayed equation does not hold. Assuming you missed a $-1$ exponent in the product, it is still wrong since $f$ is not totally multiplicative.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

The order of the pole at $s=1$ is the number of distinct irreducible factors.

Let $m\in \Bbb{Z}[x]$ monic and irreducible, $K=\Bbb{Q}[x]/(m(x))$.

$$f(n)=\# \{ a\bmod n, m(a)=0\bmod n\}$$

$f$ is clearly multiplicative. $m(x)\bmod p$ is separable when $p$ doesn't divide $Disc(m)$. For those primes Hensel lemma tells us that $f(p^k)=f(p)$ so that
$$F(s)=\sum_n f(n)n^{-s} = \prod_p (1+\sum_{k\ge 1} f(p^k) p^{-sk})$$ For the primes dividing the discriminant, I am thinking to the $\deg(m)$ roots of the polynomial in $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p$, for $k$ large enough there is a one-to-one correspondence between these and their reductions $\bmod p^k$. Not sure of the simplest argument $$=(\prod_{p\ | \ Disc(m)} (1+O(p^{-s}))\prod_{p\ \nmid\ Disc(m)} (1+f(p)\frac{p^{-s}}{1-p^{-s}})$$ $$=(\prod_{p\ | \ Disc(m)} (1+O(p^{-s}))\prod_{p\ \nmid\ Disc(m)} (1+f(p)p^{-s})(1+O(p^{-2s}))$$

For the primes not dividing the discriminant $f(p)$ is the number of prime ideals of $O_K$ with residue field $\Bbb{F}_p$ which means that
$$\prod_{P\ni p\subset O_K}\frac1{1-N(P)^{-s}}=
(1+O(p^{-2s}))\prod_{P\subset O_K,N(P)=p}\frac1{1-N(P)^{-s}}$$ $$=
 1+f(p)p^{-s}+O(p^{-2s})$$
And hence $$F(s)=\zeta_K(s)(\prod_{p\ |\ Disc(m)} (1+O(p^{-s})) (\prod_p (1+O(p^{-2s}))$$

> Since $(s-1)\zeta_K(s)$ is entire then $(s-1)F(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(s)>1/2$.

For $m$ non-monic it works the same way, multiplying $Disc(m)$ by the leading coefficient of $m$.

For $m(x) = \prod_{j=1}^J m_j(x)^{e_j}$ reducible it is mostly the same as for the primes not dividing $Disc(\prod_{j=1}^J m_j)$ $$f(p^k)=\sum_jf_j(p^k),\qquad f_j(p^k)=\# \{ a\bmod n, m_j(a)=0\bmod p^k\}$$

Letting $K_j=\Bbb{Q}[x]/(m_j(x))$ then
$$F(s)=(\prod_{p\ |\ Disc(\prod_j m_j)} (1+O(p^{-s})) (\prod_p (1+O(p^{-2s})) \prod_{j=1}^J \zeta_{K_j}(s)$$ and hence $(s-1)^J F(s)$ is analytic for $\Re(s)> 1/2$.

Comment: It might be worth emphasizing somewhere: the function $F(s)$ indeed does have a pole at $1$, but contrary to what the OP asserts, its order is *not* equal to the degree of the polynomial.

Comment: I realize that the notation $\prod_p (1+O(p^{-s}))$ is a bit ambiguous, whereas we really need it in the theory Dirichlet series. Often we can interpret it as "the LHS (a Dirichlet series) converges locally uniformly thus it is analytic" but not here.

Comment: Thank you @reuns for the answer. Helps a lot. Can you give a short proof or suggest a bijective map to prove the claim f(p^k)=\sum_j f_j(p^k)?

Comment: @kabira For the primes not dividing the Disc the $m_j \bmod p$ are separable and coprime, they have no root in common.